# MATLAB Emebedded C function issue

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

Hi I am trying to use C files in MATLAB through MEX-files but so far no luck. I followed the tutorial shown in this link: https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/integrating-matlab-into-your-cc-product-development-workflow-106742.html
I downloaded the files and works perfectly fine. Now I am trying to code a function of my own and it produces the MEX-file correctly but when I try to test the function MATLAB shuts down. The files looks as follows: [image]
In addition I have checked the following possible causes:

1. Verified that the function in c is the correct type in this case **int**.
2. Use a pointer in the c code instead of just a variable.
3. Include return in the c function.
4. Initialise the reference value of the function's output i.e. y=int32(15);
5. Include all the headers in the c code i.e.
6. The example from the link works perfectly, what I am missing?

   The c code

   ```
        #include <stdio.h>
        int bimi(int* output);
        int bimi(int* output){
           int a = 0;
           output=25;
           return output;
        }
   ```

The function in MATLAB

```
    function y = bimi()  %#codegen
             %coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','bm.c');
             y = int32(15);%coder.nullcopy(1);
             coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','bimi.c');
             fprintf('Running Custom C Code...\n\n');
             coder.ceval('bimi',coder.ref(y));%this bimi should match with the function name!
    end
```

script that is used to build MEX-file

```
    function build(target)
    %   BUILD is a build function for the Gaussian filter
    %
    %   SYNTAX:     build mex
    %               build lib
    %           
           %   Copyright 2014 The MathWorks, Inc.

        % Entry point function:
        entryPoint = 'bimi';%

        % Configuration object:
        cfg = coder.config(target);

        % Custom source files:
        cfg.CustomSource = 'bimi.c';

        % Generate and Launch Report:
        cfg.GenerateReport = true;
        cfg.LaunchReport = false;

        % Generate Code:
            codegen(entryPoint,'-config', cfg)

    end
```

test script

```
    %testing the c code embeded to matlab
    chichi=bimi_mex();
```

Comment: Try to add a `coder.cinclude` call to your MATLAB code to include the header declaring `bimi`. You should see a compile warning about not having a declaration. Also your `bimi` returns a pointer rather than the value pointed to. Should it return `*output`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is by being very careful with the file names and functions name (That was the issue, simple, basic but takes time to spot). Take a look to the last test I performed which works perfectly fine:

The files are:

```
//bimi.c
#include "bimi.h"

extern void bimi(int* poly, int* polysz, int* output){
    int i;
    int a=*(polysz);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        output[i]=2*poly[i];
    }
}
```

.

```
//bimi.h
extern void bimi(int* poly, int* polysz, int* output);
```

.

```
//bimifunc.m
function y = bimifunc(poly2, polysz2)  %#codegen
         %coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','bm.c');
         y = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,5,'int32'));%coder.nullcopy(1);
         coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','bimi.c');
         fprintf('Running Custom C Code...\n\n');
         coder.ceval('bimi',coder.ref(poly2),coder.ref(polysz2), coder.ref(y));%this bimi should match with the function name!
end
```

.

```
//build.m
function build(target)
    % Entry point function:
    entryPoint = 'bimifunc';%

    %Example input
    poly=zeros(1,5, 'int32');
    polysz=int32(length(poly));

    % Configuration object:
    cfg = coder.config(target);

    % Custom source files:
    cfg.CustomSource = 'bimi.c';
    cfg.CustomSourceCode = [ '#include "bimi.h"' ];

    % Generate and Launch Report:
    cfg.GenerateReport = true;
    cfg.LaunchReport = false;

    % Generate Code:
    codegen(entryPoint,'-args', {poly, polysz},'-config', cfg)

end
```

.

```
//test.m
%testing the c code embeded to matlab
poly=ones(1,5, 'int32');
polysz=int32(length(poly));

chichi=bimifunc_mex(poly, polysz);
```